# Using files instead of directories in find command

Tags: bash, find

I am using the find command on a number of directories stored in `fdir` array to execute head on each file.  How can I adapt the code to also use files in `fdir`?

```
nf=${#fdir[@]}
for (( i=0 ; i < $nf ; i++ )); do
  find "${fdir[$i]}" -type f \
    -exec head -v -n "$hn" '{}' + 
done
```

Comment: "use files" meaning what, in this context?

Comment: Currently I pass a list of directories in `fdir`.  E.g. `fdir=("$HOME/Opstk")`.  I want to be able to use head directly on specified files such as using `fdir=("$HOME/Opstk/lin.sh")`.

Comment: So... does `fdir` contain **both** files, and directories that you wish to search (recursively) for files? BTW for directories only, unless `fdir` has a very large number of elements you should be able to omit the loop and just do `find "${fdir[@]}" -type f ...`

Comment: I can either put both directories and files in `fdir`, or have option for files.  I was hoping to just have the user pass a list of either directories or files so things are straightforward.

Comment: Well... it's probably not very efficient, but you can actually pass plain files as starting points to GNU find

Comment: You mean passing filenames when one usually puts directory names?

Comment: I could each whether the array element is a directory (using `[[ -d  "${fdir[$i]}"]]`) or a file (using `[[-f "${fdir[$i]}"])`.

Comment: For instance, I can use the `find` command for directories, whilst calling `head` directly for files.

Comment: Have seen that `grep` works differently, in the sense that one can pass both directories and files.  `find` does not behave in such a way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synopsis of the GNU `find` command is

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [starting-point...] [expression]
```

where `[starting-point...]` is zero or more paths. It's probably not very efficient, but there's nothing to stop you passing files as starting points ex. given:

```
$ cat subdir/somefile
foo
bar
baz
```

then

```
$ find subdir/somefile -type f -exec head -n 2 {} +
foo
bar
```

As well, there's no need to limit the command to a single starting point - **unless** your array is large enough to exceed the kernel's `ARG_MAX` limits<sup>1</sup>, so you likely can just do

```
find "${fdir[@]}" -type f -exec head -v -n "$hn" '{}' +
```

regardless of the mix of directories and files in `fdir`. Just be aware that if `fdir` includes both a file AND its containing director, then you will get duplication, ex.:

```
$ fdir=(subdir subdir/somefile)

$ find "${fdir[@]}" -type f -exec head -n 2 {} +
==> subdir/somefile <==
foo
bar

==> subdir/somefile <==
foo
bar
```

---

1. see for example [CP: max source files number arguments for copy utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110282/cp-max-source-files-number-arguments-for-copy-utility)